# Form submission redirect dependent upon user input

Tags: html, forms, redirect, input

Apologies in advance - I'm very much new to all coding and need a bit of help.

Here's my current HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="form_output.htm">
      Input:<br>
      <input type="text" name="input" value="Enter here">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
    <p>Click 'Submit' to continue.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Pretty simple as it stands...

But - I need it to redirect the user to a specific page based upon their input.

For example, if the user was to input `cat`, I'd want the target page to be `form_output_cat.htm`.

Not sure if this is doable using HTML alone but any guidance would be much appreciated :)

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `action` attribute when the user change the value in the `input`.

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function() {
  form.setAttribute('action', 'form_output_' + this.value + '.html');
});

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('form should send to: ' + form.getAttribute('action'));  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="form_output.htm">
      Input:<br>
      <input type="text" name="input" placeholder="Enter here">
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
    <p>Click 'Submit' to continue.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this JavaScript do what you want?

Add it in a `<script>` tag at the bottom, right before `</body>`.

```
const input = document.querySelector("[name=input]");
const form = input.parentNode;
input.addEventListener("input", () => {
  form.action = `form_output_${input.value}`;
});
```

Comment: @MoshFeu It is. It works on browsers that existed before I was even born if [transpiled](https://babeljs.io). Plus, all modern browsers meanwhile support `const`, arrow functions and template strings, so it should run without any issues. No problem here.

Comment: Thank you.. I learned something new. Although, as I understood, babel is a compiler but not natively support in old browsers. I think that if you use it in your answer, you need to mention this because people like me (2 minutes ago ;)) or who that can't use babel need to know about it.

Comment: @MoshFeu That's correct, browsers like IE6 will never *natively* support ES6 (I might update this post once physicists decide that time machines could be a thing). However, If you transpile your JS before you ship it, even IE6 will run your code. But for the sake of people from some time in the future: Just use it; native browser support is quite great today for modern browsers. :)